# ¿Porqué cae mi aplicación dentro del try catch?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, backend, async-await, try-catch

espero me puedan colaborar con un problema que estoy teniendo. tengo el siguiente código en mi backend.

```
exports.iniciarSesion = async (req, res,) => {
  try {
    const { usuario, pass } = req.body;
    const user = await modelUsers.findOne({ usuario });
    if (!user) {
      res.status(404).send("El usuario no existe");
    }
    const checkPass = await comparar(pass, user.pass);
    const tokenSesion = jwt.sign({ id: user._id, role: user.role }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: "1h", });

    if (checkPass) {
      res.send({
        data: user,
        token: tokenSesion
      })
    } else {
      res.status(404).send("La contraseña es incorrecta");
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).res("Error en el post");
  }
};
```

El problema es que al realizar el inicio de sesión, si pongo mal el usuario, mi aplicación cae, porque me da el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pass')
    at exports.iniciarSesion (C:\Users\ANDRES\Documents\portafolio\portafolio\backend\controller\controladorUsuarios.js:47:49)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
C:\Users\ANDRES\Documents\portafolio\portafolio\backend\controller\controladorUsuarios.js:64
    res.status(500).res("Error en el post");
                    ^

TypeError: res.status(...).res is not a function
    at exports.iniciarSesion (C:\Users\ANDRES\Documents\portafolio\portafolio\backend\controller\controladorUsuarios.js:64:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Pero si pongo el usuario bien y la contraseña mal, funciona perfectamente. Buscando una solución encontre que debía poner lo siguiente:

exports.iniciarSesion = async (err, req, res, next) => {

Si lo hago de esa manera, no cae la aplicación, pero no me deja enviar nuevas solicitudes, ni me devuelve el token cuando pongo los datos correctos, practicamente no me funciona. Les agrdezco su ayuda y opiniones de como solucionar este inconveniente.

Comment: En el res.status tienes res para mostrar un mensaje, normalmente se usa send no será eso el segundo error.

Comment: En el if al no encontrar usuario el proceso continúa aunque no encuentre nada, pon un exit o return para detener el proceso.

Comment: Ayudaría entender cual es la línea 47 (donde te indica que esta el error). Asumiendo que es esta "const checkPass = await comparar(pass, user.pass); " entiendo que el error no es cuando ponen mal la password sino el usuario. Como el usuario está mal, no lo encuentra y por consiguiente es null. Luego al hacer user.pass te da error porque user es null

Comment: @hejevero muchas gracias por la ayuda, poniendo el "return" se ha solucionado.

Comment: Que bueno que te sirvió, saludos.